# Mining custom coin

Tags: erc-20, mining

I made my own custom ERC20 coin for my DApp and want to have people mine for and utilize my coin instead of ETH on a private chain, is there a guide to help me do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand "mining."

The Ethereum network is secured by PoW mining. That ensures that your token code executes as written.

If you want to incentivize users to do something and reward them for doing so then that is a matter of defining the economics of your system. You would codify those rules.

It's the same principle on private chains based on Ethereum.

Hope it helps.